# i want to create bank account, but in response it is returning nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter

#### My code:

```
function stripe_bank_payment()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $id = $_GET['id'];  
    $acc_id = $_GET['stripe_account_id'];
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];
    $get = $this->db->select('*')->where(array('user_id' => $id))->get('bank_detail');
    $pay = $get->result_array();

    foreach ($pay as $res) {
      $token = $res['token'];
     }

    require_once 'stripe/init.php';

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_6zdfZQ6R0Jh7EiFONJTpYaFl");

    $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve("acct_1AaeELC0B93yNc9d");

    $account->external_accounts->create(array("amount" => $amount, "currency" => "usd", "external_account" => $token));

    return $account;

       }
```

I am passing `user_id`, `amount`, `stripe account` id and getting token from  `bank_detail` table.

I want to create bank account, but in response it is returning nothing.

Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are using get method?

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari yes sir,

Comment: you mentioned you passed user_id.....but you used $_GET['id'];